# elementary OS won't boot after install

Tags: system-installation, boot

Just tried twice installing elementary OS via a usb stick. After install it restarts but gets back to the install prompt ie it still boots from the stick. I reboot and go to the BIOS to revert back the sequence to having the HD first and remove the stick. On reboot it goes to a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

Pardon the newbie question.

My laptop is a Samsung rv511, i3.

Using elementary OS via the stick to test it out was fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Now I can't even run it off the usb stick and in the BIOS it seems like my HDD's password is frozen. I also get an error saying "Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi"

Comment: please add the update in the question through editing